# Blueprism, poner fecha actual como nombre de un excel en Blueprism

Tags: excel, blueprism

soy nuevo en BluePrism. Tengo un archivo `archivo.xlsx` y necesito moverlo de carpeta y cambiar su nombre. El nombre debe tener el formato `archivo_ddmm.xlsx` ("ddmm" Día y mes actual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer lo que comentas te puedes ayudar de los VBO genéricos que proporciona BluePrism.

En este caso puedes usar el VBO "Utility - File Management". Este VBO tiene una acción de mover con dos parámetros de entrada:

- Path origen (Ruta del fichero que quieres mover)
- Path destino (Ruta + nombre de fichero del destino)

En caso que quieras cambiar el nombre final. Puedes hacer uso de Format Date en la expresión del parámetro de destino:
Por ejemplo:
"C:\NUEVO_DESTINO\" & "NombreFichero"  & FormatDate(Now(); "ddMM")  & ".xlsx"